# PHP 7 como puedo ver el error que estoy teniendo en un input file

Tags: php, html, php7, fileupload

Estoy subiendo una imagen desde movil , me llega a este fichero `subida_imagen.php`

Pero me esta diciendo que tengo un error,

```
$fileError = $_FILES['imagen']['error'];
```

le hago un `var_dump($fileError)` y obtengo lo siguiente:

```
array(size=5)
  'name'=> string : '1675157615761576171651757165.jpg'
  'type'=> string ''
  'tmp_name'=> string ''
  'error'=> int 1
  'size'=> int 0
```

Como puedo **saber** el error que me esta dando? solo me dice que tengo un error, **pero cual es?**

Answer (score 2):

Desde la documentación [Explicación de los mensajes de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php):

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
>
> Valor: 1; El fichero subido excede la directiva [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) de php.ini.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a configurar `php.init` **¿tiene algun limite o puedo poner lo que yo quiera?**

Comment: Eso depende de tu servidor... pero `upload_max_filesize ` debe ser igual o menor de `post_max_size` [+ info](https://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: En mi `php.ini` tengo los siguientes valores en las siguientes propiedades : `memory_limit = 128M` , `upload_max_filesize = 20M`, `post_max_size = 20M`

Comment: Vale, perfecto. Ya lo consegui, era un error de codigo despues de comprobar si habua una foto para subir ponia la foto a nulo siempre pues no estaba haciendo bien la estructura de control `if(){}else{}`

Comment: Ok... me alegro... saludos!